# How to count blog categories in django and display them in a template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

am new in django am developing a blog which has functions post_list,category_detail and post detail am stuck 
in post_list function which renders a blog.html i want to display the blog category which are python and hardware together with the total number of posts in that category 
i have tried my ways it shows the wrong way since there should be six posts in python category and one post in hardware category [see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZdgU.jpg)  please check the codes and help out

views.py

```html
def post_list(request):
    object_list=Post.objects.filter(status='Published').order_by("-created")
    recent_post=object_list[:4]
    category_list_count=Post.objects.annotate(num_category=Count('Category'))


    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context={
        'items':items,
        'recent_post':recent_post,
        'category_list_count':category_list_count,
    }
    return render(request,"blog.html",context)
```

blog.html

```html
      <div class="widget">
          <h3 class="badge">CATEGORIES</h3>
{% for obj in category_list_count %}
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{% url 'category_detail' slug=obj.Category.slug %}">{{obj.Category}}</a> <span class="badge">{{obj.num_category}}</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# You should change post in Count function based on your model.
categories = Category.objects.all().annotate(posts_count=Count('post'))
```

Then you will have access to number of posts for each category:

```
for category in categories:
    print(category.posts_count)
```

In your template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
      <p>Number of posts: {{category.posts_count}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Am getting an error NoReverseMatch at /blog/   Reverse for 'category_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/category\\-detail\\/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Comment: Thank you worked i had to change the url from {% url 'category_detail' slug=obj.Category.slug %} to {% url 'category_detail' category.slug %}

Comment: Just one thing cant figure out  is this   <li><a href="{% url 'category_detail' category.slug %}">{{category}}</a> <span class="badge">{{category.post_count}}</span>      as you can see the picture i attached it has to be category and the badge count of posts please help out